# Browser Resize using jQuery

Tags: jquery, browser, resize

I have a application logic page, in which we have to make it re-size to maximized state; i got some solutions on the internet but they say about window resize using resizeTo() or resizeBy(). But somehow Chrome doesnot allow these functions.

I need to make the browser to be maximized in Chrome and IE8. Please say me some suggestions or someone has faced this issue earlier.

Thanks in advance!!1

Comment: Look at this.. I dont know if that helps you...http://www.gtalbot.org/BugzillaSection/Bug195867GDR_WindowOpen.html#GrpPositionSizeFeatures

Answer (score 1):

You can't force this as:

- Chrome may not implement this in the near future: [Issue 2091:    window.resizeTo() doesn't have any effect](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2091)
- in IE the security zones can prevent this and other events/actions from being fired
- in IE it might only work (if security zone allows it) if you open the link in a new window